# Probably an ambiguous word problem

Tags: combinatorics, word-problem

I don't know if this should have been posted on English because it's about interpretation of a sentence, or Math because it involves with a math problem to get the right context and interpretation...

Anyways, here's the problem:

> Restaurant A had just put out a new combination meal set. Each set costs $89 and customers can choose one main dish, one side, and one drink. The followings are the choices:
>
> Main dish : Chicken Burger, Hamburger, Fish Burger, Double Burger
>
> Side : Chicken Nuggets, French Fries, Apple Pie
>
> Drink : Coke, Coffee, Milk Tea
>
> However, there are two restrictions to certain combinations such as: **Fish Burger and Chicken Nuggets must come together, Chicken Burger cannot go with Coffee**. Except these two restrictions, customers can mix and match any other combinations. How many different combination sets are available to customers?
>
> **(A)** 12 **(B)** 13 **(C)** 25 **(D)** 28

An easy question, I know, but this turned out to be ambiguous.

I interpret the sentence written in bold as:

1. Fish Burger and Chicken Nuggets are inseparable, so Fish Burger *have* to go with Chicken Nuggets as the side, and Chicken Nuggets can only be ordered with Fish Burger as the main dish
2. Every set with Chicken Burger as main dish, cannot have Coffee as the drink

And I calculated

```
Chicken Burger : 2 possible sides * 2 possible drinks =  4
Hamburger      : 2 possible sides * 3 possible drinks =  6
Fish Burger    : 1 possible side  * 3 possible drinks =  3
Double Burger  : 2 possible sides * 3 possible drinks =  6
                                                        -- +
                                                        19 combinations total
```

...which don't appear in the choices. So either I am wrong with interpreting that sentence, or this problem is badly worded.

What's your take on interpreting this?

Comment: "Milk Tea" is one drink?  Never heard of it.  Sure they didn't mean "Milk, Tea"?  Mind you...that gets you to $26$ possible orders, also not an option.

Comment: @lulu haha yep it's one drink. It is tea mixed with milk. I gave you the benefit of the doubt and calculated anyways, and the result is 26 combinations. Not in the choices though, unfortunately

Comment: @lulu "milk tea" is 1 drink. Its just black tea with milk

Comment: You are right...I just looked it up.  I read the problem the same way you did, but I suppose they must mean that the Fish lovers must choose the Chicken nuggets, but anyone else may also choose the chicken nuggets.  I agree it is poorly worded.

Comment: @Qwerty  So it seems!  Just looked it up. Learn something every day.

Comment: @possibility0  But then...The Chicken Burger people have 3 sides and 2 drinks, so $6$.  The Hamburger folk have $3\times 3 = 9$, the Fish folk have $3$ drinks, and the Double people have $3\times 3=9$.  Whence $6+9+3+9=27$. Again, not an option.  I share your frustration!

Comment: @lulu phew, I think I got the answer. Here goes: Let's say that Fish Burger doesn't have to pair with Chicken Nuggets, but Chicken Nuggets has to pair with Fish Burger. That would give us... $4 + 6 + 9 + 6 = 25$ combinations! If that's the correct interpretation, this problem is way poorly worded.

Comment: Clever you to get a reading that fit.   Sure...this is possible and I expect you've got it right.  But this was badly phrased and I expect this particular reading would be in the deep minority.  As a side note:  $\$89$ is far too much to charge.  And why exactly can't I have coffee with my Chicken burger?  For $\$89$ I would expect champagne!

Comment: @lulu hahaha champagne indeed xD

Comment: If they are charging $89 for a meal like this they had **better** include champagne!

Answer (score 1):

Fish Burger must go with chicken nuggets, so there are only 3 combinations that fish burger can have (as there are 3 drinks and only 1 side). Chicken burger must not go with coffee so there are 3 sides and 2 drinks for the chicken burger, so there are 6 total combinations with the chicken burger. And finally, the double burger and hamburger can go with 3 sides and 3 drinks, so there are 18 total there (9 for double and 9 for hamburger). Therefore there are 3+6+18=27. Which isn't an available answer. But it works if you say that chicken nuggets can only go with fish burger and fish burger is free to take all 3 sides, as you then get 9+4+6+6=25. It's just a poorly worded question.